# YouTube Data API playlistitems.list-method doesn't respond

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The YouTube Data API playlistitems.list-method doesn't respond since approximately 20 hours ago.

The following URL would have normally returned all the videos in that playlist: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252Cid&id=UUuQHD9MgnRILjwdQaWZrBxA&fields=items%252Fid&_h=1&

Does anybody have an update on the method's status?

Comment: May be your daily limit exceed.Please try with different token..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided, it looks like you're providing the **`playlistID`** as the **`playlistItemId`**. It works when you provide the playlist ID in the correct field:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252Cid&playlistId=UUuQHD9MgnRILjwdQaWZrBxA&_h=3&
```